# I have a Yahoo email account that just got hacked and now I can't send out emails

Tags: yahoo-mail, hacked, phishing

I have a Yahoo email account that just got hacked as someone used it to send spam to many of my contacts.  I just changed my password. I've been trying to send emails to a few contacts that we're affected but it seems like I'm being prevented by Yahoo to send these emails. It's giving me a message:

> Your email could not be sent. Retry

I've clicked "Retry" several times but to no avail.

Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: We'd need more details...

Comment: I wonder if it had anything to do with SMTP? Or browser. It was just bizzare. It's working now. The problem happened while I was using Chrome then hours later I logged back in on Yahoo via Firefox and it was able to send the mail.